# Can you import a file which already contains reactDOM render calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a legacy enterprise application which contains numerous components which are rendered to multiple anchor points on the page. example below

`modals.js`

```js
import etc
class MyModal extends Component {
  render() {
     return <span>a modal</span>
  }
}

var modals = $('.react__modal');
if (modals.length) {
   modals.each(function() {
      ReactDOM.render(<MyModal />,this);
   });
}
```

now suppose I have multiple areas to this app such as `admin.js`, `frontend.js`, `account.js`, could I import `modals.js` in some what to be included within all these areas or would I have to export the class and then have multiple declarations of my `ReactDOM.render` in each of my areas.

I have approximately 100 components like this, and I'd rather not have to duplicate the render across all areas (6 in total).

Currently using gulp to compile, but in the process of moving to webpack (using laravel mix).

Comment: You can import them. And you better to not have such files, instead place a class and side effects (render) to different modules.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use export:

```
export default class MyModal extends Component
```

Then in other components you can import it and use:

```
import MyModal from "./yourPathToComponent"
```